# Close pop-up window on website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I'm trying to scrape some information from a website and can't get through a pop-up window. I've tried using short and full Xpath of the X button but it doesn't close.

here is my code

```
# import 
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe') 

driver.get('https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS')

driver.find_Element_By_xpath('//*[@id="simplemodal-container"]/a').click();
```

The code does open the website but doesn't close the pop-up. What might be the issue?

Comment: I'm guessing that the popup doesn't appear straight away so it doesn't find it. Make it sleep for a few seconds and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You automation script needs an explicit waits, and the below xpath :-

```
//a[@title='Close']
```

**Code : -**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Close']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code as is:

```
# import 
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'mypath/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get('https://ai.fmcsa.dot.gov/SMS')
driver.find_Element_By_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[7]/a[1]').click();
```

This worked for me and closed the pop up window.

Comment: This one is not working for me, I'm not sure why but the one offered by cruisepandey below does.